# Prove that every complex matrix is similar to an upper triangle one

Tags: linear-algebra

I haven't been able to find a proof of this result online. Is there any proof that is relatively simple to understand? In particular, I want to also show that the upper triangle matrix that is similar to the complex one has diagonal values that are the eigenvalues of the complex one.

Comment: Look up the Jordan normal form.

Comment: @ajd we haven't covered that concept, but it seems to be an application of the theorem to be proved. Are there any simple proofs that a Jordan normal form will always exist?

Comment: Do you know that every complex matrix has an eigenvector? If you do, you can prove the claim by induction on the size of the matrix.

Comment: You might have a look on the *Schur* decomposition.